# Bootstrap form-group layout breaking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a form using bootstrap, but my layout is breaking at the SSN field.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">2nd to Last Landlord Name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">SSN (Social Secury Number):</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">2nd to Last Landlord Phone:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text">
        </div>
        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">DOB:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

executing this code in http://www.bootply.com/swKZ6PT3Bf you can see that breaks in the SSN field.

Comment: That's not how form-group is used.  `form-group` wraps a "set" of label / inputs - typically ONE input and ONE label in a form-group.  Because `col-lg-X` uses floats, form-group(s) are intended to wrap the floated `col` elements such that they clear the floats (among other things).

Comment: Also - try your link.  It's an empty / new bootply, not one that you've built.

Comment: I am trying to have 2 inputs per line, and a label on the left side of each input.

Comment: So - in my comments, I've indicated that this is not a minimal, verifiable, complete example.  You've got way more markup here than you need to represent the issue.  Strip the issue down to the minimum code required to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.form-group` is intended to wrap a "row" of input / labels, not wrap the entire form.

You should study css floats, and how bootstrap works.  `col-sm-x` etc uses `float: left`, and the reason your SSN field was "breaking" things was:
1. It was taller than the other elements
2. Which caused subsequent "floated" elements to "hang" on them, rather than go all the way to the left.

Additionally, you need to learn to troubleshoot.  You could have made this a MUCH smaller example, and you could (should) have saved a WORKING bootply.

I've created a working bootply for you here: http://www.bootply.com/WcsaQNKdLq

NOTE that `.form-group` only does this when inside of a `.form-horizontal`: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

I've edited below to preserve your `container`, as well as include the necessary `.form-horizontal`

Alter your markup like so:

```
<!-- preserving the container you need -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- adding the "form-horizontal".  Note that this does NOT have to be a form element, but must have both form and form-horizontal classes -->
    <form class="form form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h2>Apply Online</h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <!-- Add a form-group here -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Prospect First Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Last Residence:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- since that was 12 "columns" of the grid, start a new form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Prospect Last Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Last Landlord Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Last Landlord Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>ATT</option>
                    <option>Verizon</option>
                    <option>T-Mobile</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">2nd to Last Residence:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">eMail:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">2nd to Last Landlord Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">SSN (Social Secury Number):</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">2nd to Last Landlord Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">DOB:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Current Employer:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Interest:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>option1</option>
                    <option>option2</option>
                    <option>option3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Current Employer Contact:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Lead Source:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>option1</option>
                    <option>option2</option>
                    <option>option3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Current Employer Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Others On Lease:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Current Salary:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Previous Employer:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Previous Employer Contact:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Previous Employer Phone:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <label for="name" class="col-lg-2">Comments:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Terms</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div style="border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; height: 200px; overflow: auto; padding: 10px;">
                    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
                    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
                    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
                    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
                    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
                    <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
                        TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" value="agree"/> Agree with the terms and conditions
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <hr>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                <button id="applyApplication" name="applyApplication" type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block"
                        disabled>Submit Application
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Note:
I wrapped TWO sets of labels / inputs per `form-group`, taking a cue from your col-sizes.  Since bootstrap is designed around a 12-column grid, it would make sense that you were intending for those two sets to be included (label that is 2 wide, plus input that is 4 wide, plus label that is 2 wide, plus input that is 4 wide).

You can - as you need - adjust the col sizes, or the number / placement of the `form-group` divs.

Comment: I still getting the break in the SSN field. I wrapped two sets inside a form-group

Comment: Removing the div "container" it works, but I need that div

Comment: See revisions.  You need a `.form .form-horizontal` container also.